# Modify code created by ArcGIS Web AppBuilder

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm new with ArcGIS. I have done an app with Web AppBuilder to show a map with layers. When I click on an item layer it shows a pop-up with item info. But I want to show more information that I have to get from a database, depending on the clicked item( it could be a csv file instead of a database if it was easier).

I know how to create a web with the ArcGIS Javascript API (following the tutorials) and I know to create widgets (tutorials too..). I known to create a web with Web AppBuilder. But I don't know how to use Javascript API (for example creating a new layer) modifying the code created by the Web AppBuilder.

My idea was to create the web, map and layers with Web AppBuilder and then make modifications in the generated code using the Javascript API.

What is the best approach to show dynamically obtained information when clicking an item?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

If the data you want to show when you click a feature in the map is in the same (geo)database as your layers, you could create a Query Layer to join the data with the layer attributes. You will need to know SQL to do this. Also, you will need to use Arcmap (to publish a Mapserver with the query layer) or Arcgis Pro  (to publish a webmap with the query layer) so you can query the data. More on query layers you can find in [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/query-layers/what-is-a-query-layer-.htm).

You probably want to give more details of what exactly you are trying to accomplish, with sample data, so others can provide better answer to your question.